# In Grails, how do I handle a many-to-many with an intermediate join class in the view and controller?

Tags: grails

Let's say I have the following domains:

```
class Store {
    String name

    static hasMany = [ products: StoreProduct ]
}

class Product {
    String name

    static hasMany = [ stores: StoreProduct ]
}

class StoreProduct {
    BigDecimal discount

    static belongsTo = [ store: Store, product: Product ]
    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['store', 'product']
    }
```

In other words, there is a many-to-many relationship between `Store` and `Product` with an intermediate `StoreProduct` domain class to track the individual discount per store.

Grails has built-in support for one-to-many relationships, so you can pass in a list of IDs with the proper field name and the controller will automatically resolve the IDs to a list of entities. However, in this case it's a many-to-many with an intermediate domain class.

I've tried the following code in the `Store` edit view to allow a user to select a list of products:

```
<g:each in="${products}" var="product" status="i">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="${product.id}"/>
         ${product.name}
    </label>
</g:each>
```

But Grails throws various errors depending what I use for the `name` attribute. I've also tried the following for the `input` name:

```
products
products.product
products.product.id
product[0].product
product[0].product.id
```

But none of them work properly.

**My question is**, is there any built-in support for this kind of relationship in Grails, particularly when it comes to the view?

Comment: Not when it comes to the view. What are you passing down as `products` ? Show what the controller is sending.

Answer (score 1):

Change your domain structure as follows:

```
class Store {
    String name

    Set<Product> getProducts() {
       StoreProduct.findAllByStore(this)*.product
    }
}

class Product {
    String name
    Set<Store> getStores() {
        StoreProduct.findAllByProduct(this)*.store
    }
}

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder
class StoreProduct implements Serializable {

    BigDecimal discount
    Store store
    Product product

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['store', 'product']
        version false
    }

boolean equals(other) {
    if (!(other instanceof StoreProduct)) {
        return false
    }

    other.store?.id == store?.id &&
        other.product?.id == product?.id
}

int hashCode() {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
    if (store) builder.append(store.id)
    if (product) builder.append(product.id)
    builder.toHashCode()
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but I still don't know what to do for the view.

Answer (score 0):

From the domain classes above:-

- Either one of the domain (`Store` or `Product`) has to take the onus of the relationship by having a `belongsTo`. Refer [API](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany) for details.
- Domain class (`StoreProduct`) with `composite` primary key should implement `Serializable`.

Please also provide a stacktrace to debug if available.